# List of special charter which cause issue on post

Tags: asp.net, javascript-injection

I want to avoid script injection in my already running asp.net application, so I have added
FilteredTextBoxExtender with every text box at run time on Pagebase Init event and that works perfectly, where I have defined "<>&" charters which are invalid.

I want to know all special charters which cause an issue for script injection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `Server.HTMLEncode` and `Server.HTMLDecode`.

1. The less-than character (<) is converted to `&lt;`.
2. The greater-than character (>) is converted to `&gt;`.
3. The ampersand character (&) is converted to `&amp;`.
4. The double-quote character (") is converted to `&quot;`.
5. Any ASCII code character whose code is greater-than or equal to 0x80 is converted to &#, where  is the ASCII character value.

More details
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/ms525347%28v=vs.90%29.aspx

### Edit 1

Some SO links

[ASP.NET Server.HtmlEncode Limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1221439/asp-net-server-htmlencode-limitations)

[Why is Server.HtmlEncode required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6851874/why-is-server-htmlencode-required)

### Edit 2

You can refer to this link

[What characters or character combinations are invalid when ValidateRequest is set to true?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3118876/what-characters-or-character-combinations-are-invalid-when-validaterequest-is-se)

Comment: But if I allow those characters to be valid and even encode it, then I have to set validateRequest="false" which I cant do cause of some other security issues ..

Comment: so these are only charters which cause issue ?

Comment: @NeerajKumarGupta I have update my answer which has a similar link.